# Trouble writing to Excel file (Apache POI)

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

```
public static String already_exists(ArrayList<String> reg_id, ArrayList<String> doc_id, ArrayList<String> status) throws RowsExceededException, WriteException, IOException{
         WritableWorkbook myFirstWbook = null;
         FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C://Users//Desktop//OP_demo.xlsx"));
                XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
                 XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Java Books");

                 int rowCount = 0;
                 int columnCount = 0;
                 for(int i=0;i<reg_id.size();i++)
                    {
                      Object[][] bookData={{reg_id.get(i),doc_id.get(i),status.get(i)}};
                      Row row = sheet.createRow(rowCount++); 
                      //System.out.println(reg_id.get(i)+doc_id.get(i)+status.get(i));
                      for (Object[] aBook : bookData) 
                        {

                         for (Object field : aBook) 
                            {
                             org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell cell = row.createCell(columnCount++);

                                {
                                 cell.setCellValue(field.toString());
                                }

                            }
                         workbook.write(out);


                      }


                 }

                 out.close();  

        return "";
    }
```

Above is the code snippet I've used to write to the Excel file 'OP_Demo'. The values of arraylists reg_id, doc_id and status must be used to populate the cells. However, when I run the program, only the values of the lists at index position 0 is written to the files. Have I misplaced a particular statement within the for loops?

Comment: try moving the "workbook.write(out);" out of the loop, before calling out.close();

Comment: Hi Ankur, it worked! I'm trying to understand what difference it makes since I'm new to this. Could you please explain?

Answer (score 1):

You need to move workbook.write(out);outside of the loop. 
workbook.write(out); writes the content of workbook to the file stream, and you would need to write to the file once all the records are processed, else content of the file would get over-written every time this is executed.

```
public static String already_exists(ArrayList<String> reg_id, ArrayList<String> doc_id, ArrayList<String> status) throws RowsExceededException, WriteException, IOException{
             WritableWorkbook myFirstWbook = null;
             FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C://Users//Desktop//OP_demo.xlsx"));
                    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
                     XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Java Books");

                     int rowCount = 0;
                     int columnCount = 0;
                     for(int i=0;i<reg_id.size();i++)
                        {
                          Object[][] bookData={{reg_id.get(i),doc_id.get(i),status.get(i)}};
                          Row row = sheet.createRow(rowCount++); 
                          //System.out.println(reg_id.get(i)+doc_id.get(i)+status.get(i));
                          for (Object[] aBook : bookData) 
                            {

                             for (Object field : aBook) 
                                {
                                 org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell cell = row.createCell(columnCount++);

                                    {
                                     cell.setCellValue(field.toString());
                                    }

                                }

                          }

                     }

                     workbook.write(out); // writing the workbook to file-stream outside loop
                     out.close();  

            return "";
        }
```

You can refer to the following link : https://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-poi-reading-and-writing-excel-file-in-java/
It shows a basic example to read and write excel file using apache POI.